# modify variable name conditionally

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am new to vba programming.  I have three text boxes labeled txtDept1, txtDept2 and txtDept3. that I want to select conditional upon an integer (k)

```
Private Sub test()
Dim txtDept1, txtDept2, txtDept3, Testval As String
Dim k As Integer
txtDept1 = "Chem"
txtDept2 = "Biol"
txtDept3 = "Phys"
k = 1
Testval = Evaluate("txtDept" & CStr(k))
MsgBox (Testval)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to know. [ask]

Comment: you may want to add more details about your actual goal. Do textboxes belong to a UserForm or a Sheet? in this latter case are they "ActiveX" or "Form" controls? Are "txtDept1", ecc.. actual control names (the one you can see in their "Name" property) or just labels placed underneath each of them?

Comment: note that in VBA you son't declare a bunch of variables as you did for your `TxtDept1-3` , wich are declared as variant in your code.

Comment: if you are in a Userform, to select the labels : `Me.Controls("txtDept" & k).setfocus`.  By the way, do not use the same variable names in your code for strings than the text  boxes are named, it's too confusing !

Comment: in other advice: a text box is a specific control , a label is an other. so don't say "text boxes are labeled..."

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using an array instead:

```
Option Base 1

Private Sub test()

Dim txtDept As Variant, Testval As String
Dim k As Integer

txtDept = Array("Chem", "Biol", "Phys")

k = 1            'the first from the above array elements

Testval = txtDept(k)

MsgBox (Testval)

End Sub
```

<sub>Important: don't forget to include the above `Option Base 1` into your code when you copy. This is due to the fact that VBA normally starts to count the elements in an array starting with 0. So, 0 would be (in your case) `Chem` and `Biol` would be 1. With the `Option Base 1` you are telling VBA to start counting with 1 and you will get the correct result.</sub>

Comment: Arrays are zero-based in pretty much every single language out there. `Option Base 1` is one of those "help the beginner" features that actually hinder proper learning IMO. But +1 for answering a pretty unclear question.